# How to update value from another page into Code.gs array list to be pass into spread sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My google sheet updating column in my spreadsheet as undefined. This is fine when I just pass the argument directly to the append function without using an array.

```
col1        col2
undefined   undefined
```

What I'm expecting is.

```
col1    col2
image1  image3
```

> main Code.gs

```
var list1=[];
var url1='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ltZN-Gc6G6WJF9tJ-GRPjdXczlpp0IKWU1yJLszBxI/edit#gid=0';
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url1);
var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");


function page1(id){
  ws.appendRow(list1.push(id));
}

function page2(id){ 
list1.push([id]);
}

function lastPage(){
    ws.appendRow([list1[0],list1[1]]);
}
```

> page1.html

```
<?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=page2'>
      <img id="img4" onClick="imgClicked(this.alt)" alt="image4" src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1gcuXbhSbVM9gSeffWgw_o1zHQ5PBvdaF=s220?authuser=0' width=200 height=200/>
      </a>
    </div>


        <script>

        function imgClicked(clicked){
        var id = clicked
        google.script.run.page1(id);
        }

        </script>
```

> submit.html

```
   <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=page4'>
  <img id="img4" onClick="imgClicked()" alt="image4" src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1gcuXbhSbVM9gSeffWgw_o1zHQ5PBvdaF=s220?authuser=0' width=200 height=200/>
  </a>
</div>

    <script>

    function imgClicked(){
    google.script.run.lastPage();
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function page1(id){
  ws.appendRow(list1.push(id));
}
```

to

```
function page1(id){
   list1.push(id);
  ws.appendRow(list1);
}
```

You will understand the reason if you log

```
Logger.log(list1.push(id));
```

See  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> Return value The new length property of the object upon which the
>   method was called.

In other words, `list1.push(id)` returns you the length of the array rather than its content.